# fullpage js Horizontal scrollbar comes on ie

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, fullpage.js

Im using fullpage.js plugin for my project.it works fine in all other browsers when it comes to ie it shows a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: http://ec2015dev.ispghosting.com/ this is the link.

Comment: Check your console because it doesn't look like any `fullpagejs` files are actually on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something inside your `container` class element in the 1st section is causing the problem.

It seems your element with the class `home-banner-midle` is the cause of it. Probably because of `left:50%` and `width:100%` being absoluted positioned.